# Store only 1 values and remove the rest for same duplicated values in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have duplicated values in my data. However, from the duplicated values, i only want to store 1 values and remove the rest of same duplicated values.
So far, I have found the solution where they remove ALL the duplicated values like this.

[image: posts]

Code:

```
  SELECT ID, a.date as date.A, b.date as date.B, 
       CASE WHEN a.date <> b.date THEN NULL END AS b.date
except(date.A)

FROM
    table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b
 USING (ID)
WHERE date.A = 1
```

Sample input:

[image]

Sample output (Store only 1 values from the duplicated values and remove the rest):

[image: ![enter image description here]

NOTE: query might wrong as it remove all duplicated values.

Comment: in your data sample you have not a primary key ..  so how you can try to delete a row and not the other with same value ??' ..  update you data sample adding info for define a primary key

Comment: edited with the real database. isnt the ID is primary key? and it will be other IDs with duplicated rows

Comment: looking to your sample  .. i see alway the same value  ..  a primary key by definition must be unique .. so if you a valid primary key is easy delete duplicatedc  row otherwise is not posssible ..

Comment: Is it possible to do like ..remove *  where date > 1 for each ID (?) ..sorry not a right query, but my idea is there

Comment: Your query is really hard to follow.  You have used `except` incorrectly and the `case` expression makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your screenshot's sample data and your explanation. I understand that you want to remove duplicates from your table retaining only one row of unique data. Thus, I was able to create a query to select only one row of data ignoring the duplicates.

In order to select the rows without any duplicates, you can use [SELECT DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_distinct). According to the documentation, it discards any duplicate rows. In addition to this method, [CREATE TABLE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement) statement  will also be used to create a new table (or replace the previous one) with the new data without duplicates. The syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE project_id.dataset.table AS
SELECT DISTINCT ID, a.date as date.A, b.date as date.B, 
       CASE WHEN a.date <> b.date THEN NULL END AS b.date
except(date.A)

FROM
    table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b
USING (ID)
WHERE date.A = 1
```

And the output will be exactly the same as you shared in your question.

Notice that I used ***CREATE OR REPLACE***, which means if you set  ***project_id.dataset.table*** to the **same** path as the table within your select, it will replace your current table *(in case you have the data coming from one unique table)*. Otherwise, it will create a new table with the specified new table's name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation.  Something like this:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(a).*, ANY_VALUE(b).*
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN
     table2 b
     USING (ID)
WHERE date.A = 1
GROUP BY id, a.date;
```

For each `id/`date`combination, this returns an arbitrary matching row from`a`/`b`.